# have two callback in one jsonp file

Tags: callback, jsonp

how can I have a valid jsonp file that contains two different callback

> test.jsonp

```
a_callback({x:1});
b_callback({x:1});
```

when I put two callback in one file I get

> Uncaught ReferenceError

error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting a reference error, then you are trying to reference something that doesn't exist. The error message should tell you what that is.

There is nothing stopping you putting two function calls in a dynamically loaded JavaScript file (which is, essentially, what JSONP is).